# User inputted int to file getting 'Access violation' in C

Tags: c, file, exception, input, int

Okay so I am attempting to add data to this text file and I want to add an int, every time I attempt this I enter the int press enter, and get this error message...

"Unhandled exception at 0x77ac15de (ntdll.dll) in homework2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000."

With a window that only allows me to break or continue both of which dont really do anything until I close my cmd window. It works fine without the lines for adding an int, I had it working when it was only adding a user inputted String just fine. The code looks like so...

```
//printf("Enter the term: "); scanf("%d", input);
//THIS STUFF DOESNT WORK!
    //fprintf(inputf, "%d, ", input);

    printf("Enter last name: "); scanf("%s", name);

    fprintf(inputf, "%s,", name);

    printf("Enter first name: "); scanf("%s", name);

    fprintf(inputf, "%s,", name);
```

And I want the text to read like this in the file when I open it...

" 1301,"Doe","John J." "

Comment: If your compiler isn't warning about the mismatch in the arguments, then you should add options (if it is GCC, use `-Wall` or `-Wformat`); if the compiler can't tell you about the mismatch in the arguments, then maybe you should get a better compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function scanf() have the following prototype:

```
int scanf(const char *format, ...);
```

It is needs a pointer to the variable if it is going to change the variable itself, so you have to use the address-of operator to pass the pointer into a function.

You have to use `scanf("%d", &input);` instead of `scanf("%d", input);`

Answer (score 1):

Need to change `scanf("%d", input);` to `scanf("%d", &input);`